# How to build my own custom ci runner like circle ci in golang

Tags: go, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

Have always wanted to build my own ci runner like GitLab runner, circle ci runner in golang but I really don't know how to go about this would go a long way if anyone could please point me through

Comment: I want to build my own ci that I could communicate to using API or any other message broker to initiate some certain actions and steps e.t.c

Comment: voting to close as this is too broad to answer properly in a concise way

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx  and see what a Golang CI thing looks like